# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{\frac {\log n}{n^2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need help to calculate this limit $$\large\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{\frac {\log n}{n^2}}.$$

I know  the limit of the exponent goes to zero, but the limit of the base goes to infinity, I think the limit goes to 1, am I right?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know how to use logarithms to simplify this kind of limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Expanding on Andre's hint:

$$\log\left(n^{\frac{\log n}{n^2}}\right)=\frac{\log n\cdot\log n}{n^2}=\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^2$$

Recall that by the continuity of $\log$ we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(f(n)) = \log(\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n))$.

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Take the logarithm, using $\log(a^b)=b\log a$. The result will the square of something you undoubtedly know about.

Comment: I've already tried this, without success

Comment: The logarithm is $\frac{\log n}{n}\log n=\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^2$. I think you know that $\frac{\log n}{n}$ approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$. So our limit is $e^0$.